# Printing arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to print few arrays which are calculated in one separate function and print in another separate function than that function is called in the `main`function.
This is the first function that stores and calculates values from struct varOne

```
void function1(struct varOne arrayOne[], struct varTwo* finalMark) {
int i;
     for (i=0;i<12;i++) {
          finalMark->num1 = arrayOne[i].mark1 + arrayOne[i].mark2;
          finalMark->num2 = arrayOne[i].mark3 + arrayOne[i].mark4;
     }
}
```

This function prints out the total:

```
void function2(int totalNumber, struct varTwo* finalMark) {
     printf("%d, %d \n", finalMark->num1, finalMark->num2);
}
```

We then print out function2 in the main like this:

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){

       function2(i+1,&finalMark[i]);
    }
```

The problem is the program print one specific value 6 times, something like this:

```
45, 34
45, 34
45, 34
......
```

But it should print 6 different values because in `function1` we are storing result from all arrays!

Comment: Did you check your `arrayOne[]` contains *different* values?

Comment: @Jens yes arrayOne[] has different values about 20 different values.

Comment: OK; where is the call to function2 from function1? It would help if you could provide a minimal compilable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (i=0;i<12;i++) {
      finalMark->num1 = arrayOne[i].mark1 + arrayOne[i].mark2;
      finalMark->num2 = arrayOne[i].mark3 + arrayOne[i].mark4;
 }
```

In `function1` these two variables `num1` and `num2` gets recent value in every iteration and previous value is lost . And they contain last value stored in them . And therefore , when you print it prints all the same values.

You can write the above like this -

```
 for (i=0;i<12;i++) {
      finalMark[i].num1 = arrayOne[i].mark1 + arrayOne[i].mark2;
      finalMark[i].num2 = arrayOne[i].mark3 + arrayOne[i].mark4;
 }
```

**Note** - Just make sure you allocated your struct pointer sufficient memory .

Comment: but finalMark is not an array, so how it going to work?

Comment: @JoeWoods `[]` operator can be applied to a pointer to reduce level of indirection . Therefore , you can access it using the array subscript operator.  Read here for a explanation -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782111/does-the-bracket-operator-only-have-a-single-use

Comment: thanks for the answer. but program will still have problem when we print because we are using a loop in main to call the function 2 6 times and if we use another loop in funciton2 we will have more numbers. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeWoods I don't quite understand why do you think it wont work because of loops .

Comment: I mean we call function2 in the main function and in main we use a for loop to print out the 6 values. We are printing the values in function2 which is called in the main, so to print all 6 values we need to use a loop in function2 which will display value 12 times one from loop in function2 and one from the main function.

Comment: @JoeWoods  Don't use a loop in `main` then , use a single loop in `function2` from `0 to 12(excluding)` . Which will print all the values .  And when you call it pass `finalmarks` as whole  not address of its element .